# LEFT JOIN on a table and SELECT columns from new table of MIN(date) based on another column condition

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have table `cases`:

```
id | created_date         | owner  | status
c_1    2020-09-01 10:00:00    Tim    new
c_2    2020-09-02  9:00:00    John   open
```

and `case_history`:

```
id | case_id | created_date         | field   | old_value | new_value
ch_1  c_1       2020-09-01 12:00:00    Owner      main       Jack
ch_2  c_1       2020-09-01 13:00:00    Owner      Jack       Tim
ch_3  c_2       2020-09-02 10:00:00    Status     new        open
```

`cases` is real-time, in that it reflects the current case state. `case_history` keeps record of all changes made to a case.

What I want is to join the two tables together such that `original_owner` reflects the first case owner -  this would be the `min(created_date)` where `field = 'Owner'`. Additionally, I want the `case_history` `created_date` to be the earliest result.

Desired output:

```
id | created_date          | original_owner | status | first_modified_date
c_1  2020-09-01 10:00:00      main              new      2020-09-01 12:00:00
c_2  2020-09-02  9:00:00      John              open     2020-09-02 10:00:00
```

My attempt:

```
SELECT
id,
created_date,
c.owner AS original_owner,
status,
ch.created_date AS first_modified_date,
FROM cases c
LEFT JOIN case_history ch
ON c.id = ch.id
AND ch.created_date =
  (
      SELECT MIN(created_date)
      FROM case_history z
      WHERE 
        z.caseid = ch.caseid
  )
AND c.owner =
(
  SELECT old_value
  WHERE case_history z
  field = 'Owner'
  HAVING MIN(created_date)
)
```

I get this error: `SQL compilation error: Invalid data type [TIMESTAMP_TZ(9)] for predicate [MIN(created_date)]` . Am I using having incorrectly?

When I remove the owner code, I can get the first modified date.

If I can clarify anything please let me know! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The subquery in your third join condition looks like it has a typo. You have:

```
AND c.owner =
(
  SELECT old_value
  WHERE case_history z
  field = 'Owner'
  HAVING MIN(created_date)
)
```

I think what you want is something more like

```
AND c.owner =
(
  SELECT old_value
  FROM case_history z
  WHERE field = 'Owner'
  HAVING created_date = MIN(created_date)
)
```

Depending on your platform, the `WHERE case_history z field = 'Owner'` may still execute,  but `HAVING` expects to have the aggregate function (MIN) **compared to** some other value; in essence, it expects to receive a boolean.

Comment: I received the same error here, unfortunately I don't think this is the way to work this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
select cases.id ,  cases.owner as original_owner , status , min(cases.created_date ), min(case_hist.created_date)  first_modified_date
from cases left join case_hist 
on cases.id = case_hist.id and field = 'owner'
group by cases.id ,  cases.owner , status
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not return the min result. It returns several results due to the Group By.

Comment: I think this is on the right track, when I use the partitioning strategy such as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34596359/sql-return-min-values-multiple-rows-dynamically

however, this because this only returns 1 result (RN =1), this column cannot be joined to another table